# How to write logs to the log text file using wix

Tags: wix

I have to write logs for windows installer set up which is built using WIX.
Can we write log for each component and feature..?

I am struggling to find out a way to do this any one help me please.

Thanks
Naresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [MsiLogging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370322%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [MsiLogFileLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You can set these properties in your MSI to force logging.  Setting a logging mode like MsiLogging=icewarmupvo will include the most information in your setup logs.  Alternatively, if you have a chainer (eg burn, setup.exe) you can control the logging from there using [MsiEnableLog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370091%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I didn't understand how to implement this. can you explain where i need to mention these properties to enable logging.Can you please tell me the log file path.I am using WIX(windows installer xml) to build the msi.